# Rails 3 functional test can't find my controller

Tags: unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, functional-testing

I'm trying to test my authlogic code in my Ruby on Rails 3 app and I'm running into some trouble testing my users controller.

This is my test for the users controller

```
class UsersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should be asked to login on show action" do
    get :index
  end
end
```

And this is the section of my route which sets up the controller

```
resource :account, :controller => 'users'
```

When I run my test I get the message

`1) Error: test_should_be_asked_to_login_on_show_action(AccountsControllerTest): ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:controller=>"users"}`

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that was a school boy error.

The problem was calling index on the test. I guess when you define something as a resource as opposed to resources it doesn't get an index action. Changing it to `:show` worked for me.